# how to share content from one activity to email or mobile or other applications using button.Click

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using visual studio 2015 community and under c# node under android option I am creating one application. where On activity I have placed one button Named 'share' and after button click I want to share content of activity(intent's)  to sent to other person using mail or WhatsApp or SMS. My question is How to do that.
please help.

Comment: If you want help on Stackoverflow its recommendable to describe your problem precise and in good english. For me its hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2015 community and under c# node uner android option I am creating one application. where On activity I have placed one button  Named share and after button click I want to share activity contents using mail or WhatsApp or sms to other person  and my question is How to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          I could able to sort out my own question using below codes.

           private void Share_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {

            var myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

           myIntent.SetType("text/plain");
           myIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "text");
           myIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "text");
           StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(myIntent, "Choose an App"));
           }
```